# Get the Flask view function that matches a url

Tags: python, flask, werkzeug

I have some url paths and want to check if they point to a url rule in my Flask app.  How can I check this using Flask?

```
from flask import Flask, json, request, Response

app = Flask('simple_app')

@app.route('/foo/<bar_id>', methods=['GET'])
def foo_bar_id(bar_id):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return Response(json.dumps({'foo': bar_id}), status=200)

@app.route('/bar', methods=['GET'])
def bar():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return Response(json.dumps(['bar']), status=200)
```

```
test_route_a = '/foo/1'  # return foo_bar_id function
test_route_b = '/bar'  # return bar function
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

[`app.url_map`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/api/#flask.Flask.url_map) stores the object that maps and matches rules with endpoints.  [`app.view_functions`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/api/#flask.Flask.view_functions) maps endpoints to view functions.

Call [`match`](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/latest/routing/#werkzeug.routing.MapAdapter.match) to match a url to an endpoint and values.  It will raise 404 if the route is not found, and 405 if the wrong method is specified.  You'll need the method as well as the url to match.

Redirects are treated as exceptions, you'll need to catch and test these recursively to find the view function.

It's possible to add rules that don't map to views, you'll need to catch `KeyError` when looking up the view.

```
from werkzeug.routing import RequestRedirect, MethodNotAllowed, NotFound

def get_view_function(url, method='GET'):
    """Match a url and return the view and arguments
    it will be called with, or None if there is no view.
    """

    adapter = app.url_map.bind('localhost')

    try:
        match = adapter.match(url, method=method)
    except RequestRedirect as e:
        # recursively match redirects
        return get_view_function(e.new_url, method)
    except (MethodNotAllowed, NotFound):
        # no match
        return None

    try:
        # return the view function and arguments
        return app.view_functions[match[0]], match[1]
    except KeyError:
        # no view is associated with the endpoint
        return None
```

There are many more options that can be passed to [`bind`](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/latest/routing/#werkzeug.routing.Map.bind) to effect how matches are made, see the docs for details.

The view function can also raise 404 (or other) errors, so this only guarantees that a url will match a view, not that the view returns a 200 response.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the @davidism answer (The core developer of flask).
Note that if you want to discover the view function of the current url processed by flask app. You can use the `Request` object of flask which :

> The request object used by default in Flask.  Remembers the
> matched endpoint and view arguments.

and the `Flask.view_functtions` which:

> #: A dictionary mapping endpoint names to view functions.
> #: To register a view function, use the :meth:`route` decorator.

```
 def get_view_function():
     if request.url_rule:
        return current_app.view_functions.get(request.url_rule.endpoint, None)
```

Answer (score 0):

To complement the other answers given here, for anyone who wants to do this for [Flask's class-based views](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/views/#class-based-views), you will see that [`app.view_functions`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/api/#flask.Flask.view_functions) returns the view method of the base View class, not the concrete class in which you defined your view:

```
In [4]: rule_generator = app.url_map.iter_rules()

In [5]: rule = next(rule_generator)

In [6]: rule

Out[6]: <Rule '/api/helloworld' (GET, OPTIONS, HEAD) -> helloworld_view>

In [7]: app.view_functions.get(rule.endpoint, None)

Out[7]: <function test_app.views.View.as_view.<locals>.view(**kwargs: Any) -> Union[ForwardRef('Response'), str, bytes, List[Any], Mapping[str, Any], Iterator[str], Iterator[bytes], Tuple[Union[ForwardRef('Response'), str, bytes, List[Any], Mapping[str, Any], Iterator[str], Iterator[bytes]], Union[ForwardRef('Headers'), Mapping[str, Union[str, List[str], Tuple[str, ...]]], Sequence[Tuple[str, Union[str, List[str], Tuple[str, ...]]]]]], Tuple[Union[ForwardRef('Response'), str, bytes, List[Any], Mapping[str, Any], Iterator[str], Iterator[bytes]], int], Tuple[Union[ForwardRef('Response'), str, bytes, List[Any], Mapping[str, Any], Iterator[str], Iterator[bytes]], int, Union[ForwardRef('Headers'), Mapping[str, Union[str, List[str], Tuple[str, ...]]], Sequence[Tuple[str, Union[str, List[str], Tuple[str, ...]]]]]], ForwardRef('WSGIApplication')]>
```

The solution is just an extra step, which is to call the `view_class` member:

```
In [8]: rule_endpoint = app.view_functions.get(rule.endpoint, None)

In [9]: rule_endpoint.view_class

Out[9]: test_app.views.HelloView
```

To handle a mix of view functions and classes, you can do something like:

```
if hasattr(view, "view_class"):
    view_definition = view.view_class
else:
    view_definition = view
# Do something with this information, e.g.
view_name = view_definition.__name__
```