# Call a Flask Blueprint route using a string (as route) from before_request

Tags: python, flask

I need to achieve the following with my python code:
Whenever a new request comes, say, /someurl1, it should call category_route using the URL given below in the code.

```
@app.before_request
def before_request():
    url = '/category/c6f8f568-0a25-4ea7-999c-20099effa5f1'
    # Now here I need a piece of code which calls the below route's method, with above url.


@category.route('/category/<category_id>', methods=['GET'])
def category_route(category_id):
    return {"status": "in category"}
```

The page should now be redirected.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a redirect, you can use `redirect`. I'd advise you to not use `before_request` for that.

```
@app.route('/someurl1')
def someurl():
    url = '/category/c6f8f568-0a25-4ea7-999c-20099effa5f1'
    return redirect(url)

@category.route('/category/<category_id>', methods=['GET'])
def category_route(category_id):
    return {"status": "in category"}
```

If you do not actually want to redirect, but just return the return value of your other view, you can call the function directly:

```
@app.before_request
def before_request():
    category_id = 'c6f8f568-0a25-4ea7-999c-20099effa5f1'
    return category_route(category_id)

@category.route('/category/<category_id>', methods=['GET'])
def category_route(category_id):
    return {"status": "in category"}
```

Comment: I actually do not want the page to be redirected. So, do you know a way to call this route without being redirected?

Comment: I added another way to do this to my answer.

Comment: Actually, I want it to be directly called using the route instead. Because I have a mapping old and new routes in the database. So when I get /someurl1, I check database and get '/category/c6f8f568-0a25-4ea7-999c-20099effa5f1' as new url. I want to directly call the blueprint routes using the string (of route) received from db.

Comment: Oh, okay. Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38488134/get-the-flask-view-function-that-matches-a-url