# Flask 405 Method Not Allowed - Despite Allowed

Tags: flask

I am using Flask. I understand that one should specify the allowed methods via `@app.route(<path>, methods=['GET', 'POST', ...])`. However, even though I have "GET" in the `methods` list, I still get the 405 error:

[image]

The strange thing is that the "Request Method", i.e. "GET", is one of the methods in the "Allow" field in "Response Headers", shown above. How is this possible?

Here is my function for handling the route `/session/<id>/admin`:

```py
@sessmgr.route('/session/<id>/admin', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def session_admin(id):
    ... # the details doesn't matter because they are not executed.
```

I am using the following form to submit the GET request

```html
{% extends "base.fhtml" %}
{% block title %}Redirecting...{% endblock %}
{% block styles %}
    {{super()}}
    <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="{{url_for('.static', filename='mystyle.css')}}">
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="container h-100">
        <div class="w-100 p-5">
            <h7 class="text-center">Redirecting...</h7>
        </div>
    </div>
    <form action="/session/1000/admin" method="GET" id="the-form">
        <input type="submit" id="submit">
        {% for key, value in args.items() %}
            <input type="hidden" name="{{ key }}" value="{{ value }}">
        {% endfor %}
    </form>
    <script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
         $("#the-form input[type=submit]").trigger("click");
     });
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

The form is automatically submitted as soon as the page is loaded. However, I tried removing this automatic submission and manually click on the submit button, and the same thing happens. This doesn't make sense to me. Any ideas? Thanks!

#### Update

I have tried setting `method='get'` in the `<form>` but it didn't work.

Comment: do one thing restart your server or try to change the port and try again. I've tried at my end and it is working fine.

Comment: Whenever I've run into a similar problem, the issue has always been something to do with which route was being matched. See if there is another route that could match that URI.

Comment: @noslenkwah Is there a good way to debug routing in flask? (For example, setting a break point before the route is decided?) I didn't seem to find a way to do that

Comment: I tried separating the methods into different routes (one for GET, another one for POST), but the same thing happens.

Comment: @zkytony - See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38488134/get-the-flask-view-function-that-matches-a-url) question for testing which route matches a URi